# If products is in store for user, count the number of active stores

Tags: sql, count

I want to count how many stores there are connected to a specific user that have products added to the store.

If user 1 has added one or more products to two stores, then the query will print 2. If user 1 only have added products to one store, then the query will print 1.

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM stores AS s
JOIN products AS p
ON s.id = p.id_store
WHERE p.id_user = '1'
```

This query prints 7 which means that it counts the amount of products added - not how many stores that are associated with the products.

Here's how the tables looks like:

**stores**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
```

**products**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_store` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`data_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are not performing any `group by` that why.

Comment: @Rahul..`group by` is not needed here. the query outputs the total rows in the `join`ed result set.

Comment: sample data would help

Comment: @vkp, I feel it's needed since OP wanted to count per user.

Comment: @Rahul If I use `GROUP BY` in phpMyAdmin for test, then it prints 2 rows with 7 (products) and 1 (store). If I then use this query on my website, it only prints 7 and not the amount of used stores

Comment: Could you show some table data?

Comment: @RodneySalcedo vkp have the correct answer. No need for extra show then ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
id_user, count(distinct id_store) as "count"
from products
where id_store is not null
group by id_user
```

This would give you the desired `count` per user.

Comment: Many thanks for the correct answer! I'll accept it when I can :)

Comment: Didn't you commented saying *group by is not needed here.*?

Comment: @Rahul.. i was referring to the query op had in the question, when i said `group by` isn't needed